# transpose of the exponential operator

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T:X\to X$ be a continuous and linear operator. What is the transpose operator of $e^T?$

I would like to prove that $e^{T'}=(e^T)'$. At least that equality make perfect sense because they are defined in the same domain. But if $f\in X'$

$$ (e^T)'f=f(e^T)=f(\sum \frac{T^k}{k!})=\sum\frac{f(T^k)}{k!}$$
$$ (e^{T'})(f)=e^{T'f}=e^{f(T)}=\sum \frac{(f(T))^k}{k!} $$

I'm not sure if they are the same. If not I'm still looking for some possible expression for $(e^T)'$. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $A,B\in\mathcal{B}(X)$ we have $(AB)'=B'A'$. As the consequence $(T^k)'=(T')^k$. Therefore
$$
e^{T'}
=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}(T')^k
=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}(T^k)'
=\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}T^k\right)'
=(e^T)'
$$